# Http's Api's not working on android after attaching SSL certificates on version 9 and lower

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, api, ssl-certificate

[image: Certificates installed correctly]

Api's were working fine before I added SSL certificates after adding certificates no api is working my app is in react native In IOS it is working fine but in android 9 and lower version no Api is working